# Getting value from JSON array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-scope

```
{
"websites": [{
    "A": "www.foo.com"
}, {
    "B": "www.boo.com"
}, {
    "C": "www.zoo.com"
}]
```

}

I have the above JSON array which my controllers inserts into the scope by doing the following:

```
$http.get('data/websites.json')
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.websites = data;
    });
```

In my view, I have a variable that's either A, B or C. I just need to display the corresponding website in the view.

So - to sum it up:

In my view, I want to be able to do something like: {{websites.website.B}} and it would show the corresponding website URL.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by this?

Comment: can you please explain more about this ?

Comment: You have objects in an array. Your objects should have the same names for easier access.

Comment: [check this](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp)  once . hope it will be helpful

Comment: For example: 
"websites": [{
    "url": "www.foo.com"
}, {
    "url": "www.boo.com"
}, {
    "url": "www.zoo.com"
}]

Comment: The thing is, I only want it to display the website for A on one page and B on another. So, how can I search for the value of a specific key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop through $scope.websites and match key with your view variable. If its matching then display value for that key.

Using something like:

```
    angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
      if(key == <view variable>) {
      // use value to display appropriate website
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try this code.

 <li ng-repeat="stuff in websites ">
    <a href="{{stuff.A}}" target="_blank">{{stuff.A}}</a>
    <a href="{{stuff.B}}" target="_blank">{{stuff.B}}</a>
    <a href="{{stuff.C}}" target="_blank">{{stuff.C}}</a>  
</li>
```

Comment: `Object` does not have all the three keys..It has any one of them!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you simply have to use ng-repeat to loop through your json content after you have fetched the data from your json content then simply interpolate the corresponding parts you wish to pull to your DOM elements (HTML) using the $scope service